# Virtual/Abstract fields in C#

Tags: c#, .net, oop, abstract-class

Is it possible to have a virtual/abstract field in a C# class? If so, how is it done?

Comment: No, a field is just data and doesn't contain any logic. There is nothing to override, so it doesn't make sense to have virtual fields.

Comment: Is there any way to declare a static field in the base class, but not provide a value, but make all subclasses provide the actual value?

Comment: Imo a field is an implementation detail, so this **shouldn't** be possible.

Comment: If you're looking to create something like a static 'Description' property that descendents provide, I recommend researching Attributes, which allow you to associate custom Metadata with a Type.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

A Virtual/Abstract field? No. Fields are just there to hold data. There's nothing to implement.

You can [define a Virtual/Abstract Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd3z1377.aspx) though.

Comment: This seems to do what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

You can however have virtual or abstract properties:

```
public abstract string ModelName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 10):

No, a field can only be assigned to not, overridden.

However, you could probably use a property and it would look almost the same

```
public class MyClass {
  public int MyField; //field
  public virtual int MyProperty { get; set; }  //property
}
```

both get used like so:

```
var x = new MyClass();
Debug.WriteLine("Field is {0}", x.MyField);
Debug.WriteLine("Property is {0}", x.MyProperty);
```

Unless the consumer is using reflection, it looks exactly the same.

Answer (score 9):

The first sentence of the MSDN documentation answers your question:

> The virtual keyword is used to modify a method, property, indexer or event declaration, and allow it to be overridden in a derived class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 3):

No. fields can not be virtual\abstract but properties can.

Answer (score 2):

No. You'd have to use a property to accomplish what you seem to what to do.

Answer (score 2):

An old question, but here are my 2 cents:

Though one might not be able to create a virtual field - one *can* achieve what the OP seems to be looking for, which is to have the derived class's field's value be different than the base's.

**Simply assign it the "derived" value in the constructor.**

(Though that won’t be enough if you have field initializers like `int i = 1; int j = i;`).

Answer (score 1):

**Fields are storage locations in a class - you cannot "override" them or make the virtual.**

Properties, on the other hand can be made both virtual or abstract. Properties are simply syntactic sugar around get/set methods, which do the work of retrieving or setting the property value.

Answer (score 1):

Properties can be virtual, may be you can gain on that. At least it is heavily used in NHibernate.

Basically you have to have a method to virtualize, how should the virtual field work?