# C#: Abstract List<string>

Tags: c#, abstract

C#: 
I want to write an abstract class with a method that works on a List of strings. The List will not yet be implemented in this class.
Then I want to write another classes that inherits from the abstract class and implements the List of strings.

```
class AbstractClass 
{
    protected abstract List<string> myList; // To be implemented in a child class
    void ShowList()
    {
        foreach (string member in myList) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(member);
        }
    }
}

class HelloWorld : AbstractClass
{
    new private List<String> myList = new List<string>()
    {
        "Hello", "World"
    }; 
}
```

Now C# tells me "The modifier abstract is not valid on fields. Try using a property instead."
I dont seem to get the big picture. I just want a placeholder/reference to a List in my base parent class. How is that done?

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490870/virtual-abstract-fields-in-c-sharp

Comment: A field is considered to be private. That means that you wouldn't see it in the class that inherits from your base class, thus it couldn't implement it's version of the field. The other thing is - field are just for holding data and you can't really "implement" them. Try with a virtual/abstract property.

Comment: Why does it need to be "implemented" in your derived class. You define the field in the abstract class & then initialise it in the derived class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. This will fix them:

```
abstract class AbstractClass
{
    protected abstract List<string> MyList { get; set; } // To be implemented in a child class

    void ShowList()
    {
        foreach (string member in MyList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(member);
        }
    }
}

class HelloWorld : AbstractClass
{
    protected override List<String> MyList { get; set; } = new List<string>()
    {
        "Hello", "World"
    };
}
```

Problems:

- Abstract class should be declared using `abstract class`;
- You need to use properties or methods if you want to override its functionality in a derived class;
- You were using the `new` keyword. Don't do that if you want to derive something in a derived class! Use `override` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt seem to work. VirtualStudio 2013 does not accept "{ get; set; } " with the "= new List...". If I remove the "{ get; set; }" it keeps saying "Themodifier override is not valid for this item".

Comment: @KommissarFahrner The answer is in C# 6.0 syntax.

Comment: Okay, but the answer was nevertheless very helpful for my understanding!